# Why does an arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int resolve itself?

Tags: sql, t-sql

A job has been raising an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
>   Below is the query

DDL of the tables

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Approvals](
    userr_id [int] NOT NULL,
    appro_id [int] NOT NULL,
    app_units [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    c_units [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    usedunits [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    deleted [bit] NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO approvals 
VALUES
(4262,  29, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(1717,  30, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4743,  31, 76.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4460,  33, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4488,  35, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3871,  36, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3561,  37, 12.00,  1,  3.00,   0),
(4828,  38, 36.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(3828,  39, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0),
(4101,  40, 24.00,  1,  0.00,   0)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visit](
    userr_id [int] NULL,
    appro_id [int] NULL,
    c_secondary [bit] NULL,
    auth_exceeded [bit] NOT NULL,
    tperiod [int] NOT NULL,
    contratrate [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO visit 
VALUES
(5329,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(4262,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(5244,  NULL,   0, 0, 419,  0.00),
(4205,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(4828,  NULL,   0, 0,   419,    0.00),
(5531,  NULL,   0,0,    419,    0.00),
(5558,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(4460,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(5547,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00),
(5219,  NULL,   0,  0, 419, 0.00)
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure] 
AS 

DECLARE @userr_id Int, @cnt Int
SET @cnt = 0

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR


    SELECT DISTINCT userr_id 
      FROM (SELECT userr_id, app_units, c_units, usedunits,
                   (SELECT count(*) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS count_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT count(*) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS count_all,
                   (SELECT SUM(tperiod) / 60.00 FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS th_all,
                   (SELECT SUM(tperiod) / 60.00 FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS th_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT SUM(contratrate) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id and auth_exceeded = 0) AS tr_notexceeded,
                   (SELECT SUM(contratrate) FROM Visit WHERE c_secondary = 0 and appro_id = Approvals.appro_id ) AS tr_all
              FROM Approvals where deleted = 0) t
     WHERE ((c_units = 0 and (count_all <> usedunits or count_notexceeded > app_units))
        OR  (c_units = 2 and (th_all <> usedunits or th_notexceeded > app_units))
        OR  (c_units = 3 and (tr_all <> usedunits or tr_notexceeded > app_units)))

 OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @userr_id
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  SET @cnt = @cnt + 1

  EXEC [_name_of_another_stored_procedure] @userr_id

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @userr_id
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

I think, it could be fixed by changing a data type of a column from `INT` to `BIGINT` checking if there is any with a value exceeding what an int datatype column can hold.

However, it has been resolving itself; and the error is not consistently there in the database.

What would have made this? Any possible explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the Query causing the error, it is tough to tell the reason

Comment: I've updated it with the query. Thanks.

Comment: The max value of an integer is 2,147,483,647 (2.14 Billion).  The max value of a BIGINT is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (9.2 quintillion)

Comment: John, I understand that. But the thing is, the error was there yesterday; it is not more today. This happened a week ago to. I was wondering what would be fixing it with no code change.

Comment: Did you look at what data was processed yesterday compared to what data was processed today by the (I assume) same stored procedure? Since it is a transient error, might be something in the data (errors, dirty data).

Comment: Yes, I know it is data related. But the same data there was yesterday, would stay a bottleneck. That's what I thought; and kept me confused.

Comment: Where does the error occur, i.e. does the `select` statement from the SP run without error? That would place the blame/credit on `_name_of_another_stored_procedure`. Once you know that you can focus the debugging effort in the right place.

Comment: HABO, thanks. But my concern is not fixing it. It has already fixed itself. And may be next week, I'll get another notification with this error. The fact that the error is not consistent is the thing that has been boggling.

Comment: The error could be caused by using `sum` on `int` values. Changing `SUM(tperiod)` to `SUM( Cast( tperiod as BigInt ) )` may solve the problem. Changing the data type of the column from `Int` to `BigInt` would have the same effect. (The corresponding problem with `SUM(contratrate)` would result in a complaint about overflow error converting to data type _numeric_.) Does `select Sum( tperiod ) from Approvals;` cause an error?